# Extracting only numbers from series Python

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a series that looks like:

```
ID
WTG-1
11
11-1
12B1
13-1
5
6
G7
.
.
```

I simply want to be able to extract *all* the numbers from each `ID`.

When I use my code:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=True)
```

It does extract all from the front of the line but skips a number if there is a string/letter/character breaker - ie for `11-1` it only gathers `11` without the extra 1.

I'd like the output to be:

```
ID         ID #
WTG-1      1
11         11
11-1       111
12B1       121
13-1       131
5          5
6          6
G7         7
.
.
```

Is there a way to count around the characters in between?

Comment: I will suggest adding the pandas tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `findall`

```
df.ID.str.findall('(\d+)').apply(''.join)
Out[92]: 
0      1
1     11
2    111
3    121
4    131
5      5
6      6
7      7
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Comment: I suspect this runs faster than my answer

Comment: @CharlesLandau before test it out , it is hard to say :-)

Comment: Another question but related - would the way to do this for letters be `.str.findall('([a-zA-Z ]+)').apply(''.join)` ?

Comment: @HelloToEarth yes

Answer (score 1):

`astype` and `apply` can do it.

```
df["ID"] = df["ID"].apply(lambda x: "".join(c for c in x if c.isdigit()).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or replace,

```
df['New_ID'] = df.ID.str.replace('\D+', '')

    ID      New_ID
0   WTG-1   1
1   11      11
2   11-1    111
3   12B1    121
4   13-1    131
5   5       5
6   6       6
7   G7      7
```